# Remove "~" From Auto-completed Paths in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

We're working on an MVC project and have come across an annoyance. Every time that intellisense auto-completes a path for us, it inserts a `~` at the start of the path. We don't need the `~` and have to manually remove it every time. So my question is as follows:

Is there a way to customize the intellisense settings so that it will stop adding a `~` at the start of every path?

Comment: The `~` is a very good thing to have.  There is usually no reason to remove it.